# MongoDB Java API com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError

Tags: java, api, mongodb

I'm currently working on a project using the MongoDB Java API.  I have been working on this project for a while, but have recently come across an issue that I cannot resolve.  I am trying to make a database system that is fault tolerant.  To simulate a database crashing, I have my program connect to a Mongodb server that I have made, execute a simple read or write, and then shut down the database server.  I had originally thought that this would cause certain methods that I am calling to throw a `MongoException` that I could catch and then recover from the database crash.  However, I am getting a strange stack trace that says I am throwing an EOFException, among other things.  Below is the stack trace itself.

```
Mar 04, 2013 8:06:15 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError                     
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to polaris.cs.wcu.edu/152.30.5.5:12345 b/c of error
java.io.EOFException                                                        
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:48)                             
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:33)                             
    at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)                             
    at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:40)                        
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:124)                               
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:74)                              
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:282)        
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:256)             
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:289)      
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:274)      
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)                       
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)                     
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)                      
    at edu.wcu.cs.capstone.view.AbstractViewEngine.getView(AbstractViewEngine.java:57)
    at edu.wcu.cs.capstone.transaction.ServerTransactionManager.getView(ServerTransactionManager.java:52)
    at edu.wcu.cs.capstone.transaction.ServerTransactionManager.run(ServerTransactionManager.java:183)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)                                

Caught exception                                                            
Mar 04, 2013 8:06:15 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError                     
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to polaris.cs.wcu.edu/152.30.5.5:12345 b/c of error
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [polaris.cs.wcu.edu/152.30.5.5:12345] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connec
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)                            
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)                               
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:74)                              
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:282)        
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:256)             
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:289)      
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:274)      
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)                       
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)                     
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)                      
    at edu.wcu.cs.capstone.view.AbstractViewEngine.getView(AbstractViewEngine.java:61)
    at edu.wcu.cs.capstone.transaction.ServerTransactionManager.getView(ServerTransactionManager.java:52)
    at edu.wcu.cs.capstone.transaction.ServerTransactionManager.run(ServerTransactionManager.java:183)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)                                

DB is down.                                                                 
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException               
    at edu.wcu.cs.capstone.transaction.ServerTransactionManager.run(ServerTransactionManager.java:184)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The `Caught Exception` and `DB is down.` are print statements I am using to verify I am catching certain exceptions.  Here is the relevant code:

```
public View getView(Mongo mongo, Query query) throws MongoException,        
                                                     EOFException {         
    String connected = "";                                                  
    try {                                                                   
        connected = mongo.getConnectPoint();                                
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                 
        throw new MongoException("Error.");                                 
    }                                                                       
    System.out.println("Connected: " + connected);                          

    DB           db         = mongo.getDB(query.getServer());               
    List<DBObject> viewList   = new ArrayList<DBObject>();                  

    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(query.getCollection());      
    DBCursor     cursor     = collection.find(query.getQuery(), excludeID); 

    try {                                                                   
        cursor.hasNext();                                                   
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                 
        System.out.println("Caught exception");                             
    }                                                                       
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {                                              
        viewList.add(cursor.next());                                        
    }                                                                       

    return new View(viewList);                                              
}
```

As you can see, the error is occurring when I call `cursor.hasNext()`.  I am also actually still catching the exception that is being thrown because of the `Caught exception`.  However, I am still getting a stack trace as if it was not being caught.  I am suspicious that this has something to do with the `DBPortPoolgotError()` method, but I have looked at the code for this method, and cannot determine what it is actually doing or even how it is being called.  ([GrepCode link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.1/com/mongodb/DBPortPool.java#DBPortPool.gotError%28java.lang.Exception%29))

As stated above, I thought the behavior for this type of code would have been to throw a `MongoException` when a call on that specific `Mongo` object failed because the database was no longer active.  Any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the ports that you're connecting to correct? Does this work for other commands? Is there a way you can tail the server log to confirm that mongo is receiving and responding to the query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

this happens due to the driver loosing connection. Here is an issue on the mongo bug tracker referring to it https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-481

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was because I restarted mongod without restart my java server (tomcat in my case). Restarting tomcat solved this issue because the mongo driver was lost